# Haml and Rails: Deleting the space between two paragraphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using HAML and Ruby on Rails.

I have a span tag which makes both paragraphs ending up on the same line. I'd like to delete the space before `says:` as there are two spaces and it's a matter of aesthetics to me. How should I get rid of it? Here is my code:

```
#comments
    %h2.comment_count= pluralize(@post.comments.count, "Comment")
    - @comments.each do |comment|
        .comment
            %span
                %p.username= comment.user.name
                %p.username says:
            %p.content= comment.content
```

Note: It's a webpage with a post with comments. The form for writing a comment is on the same page as the show page, just in case this knowledge might affect the answer.

Comment: `<p>` isn't [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element) so you can't say `<span><p>...</p><p>...</p></span>`, you'll end up with (AFAIK) `<span></span><p>...</p><p>...</p>` instead when the browser has fixed your markup. Fix your HAML to produce valid HTML, adjust your CSS to match your new HTML, and see if it looks right. If it doesn't then update your question with the new HAML and any relevant CSS.